# How to extract an element's content in HTML?

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup

This is the fixed html content that I extracted using soup.findAll

```
myAdds = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "data"})

<div class="data">
  <img src="/page1/page2/Images/pic.png" height="13" width="13">
  &nbsp; SOME_TEXT
  </img>
</div>
```

Now, I just want

```
SOME_TEXT
```

as my final result. I neither want  tag and   elements from class="data".
I tried using replace method but it didn't work. How can I get the desired result ?

Comment: is that <img>Sometext</img>

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ: no, `img` is an empty tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want use `Tag.next_sibling` here, from the contained image tag:

```
>>> soup.find('div', class_='data').img.next_sibling
u'\n  \xa0 SOME_TEXT\n'
```

In this case, there doesn't appear to be any other text in your tag *anyway*; you may as well use the `Tag.get_text()` method:

```
>>> soup.find('div', class_='data').get_text()
u'\n\n  \xa0 SOME_TEXT\n'
```

If you have HTML with the text *contained within* a `<img/>` tag, then that's broken HTML and different parsers will handle this differently:

```
>>> sample = '''\
... <div class="data">
...   <img src="/page1/page2/Images/pic.png" height="13" width="13">
...   &nbsp; SOME_TEXT
...   </img>
... </div> 
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.div
<div class="data">
<img height="13" src="/page1/page2/Images/pic.png" width="13">
    SOME_TEXT
  </img>
</div>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, 'lxml')
>>> soup.div
<div class="data">
<img height="13" src="/page1/page2/Images/pic.png" width="13"/>
    SOME_TEXT

</div>
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.div
<div class="data">
<img height="13" src="/page1/page2/Images/pic.png" width="13">
    SOME_TEXT
  </img>
</div>
```

In all these cases, `Tag.get_text()` will work.

Comment: I have all the results stored in myAdds. For each element of myAdds, I want to extract "SOME_TEXT". I cant use soup now. It is like
`for x in myAdds:
    solve_for(x)`

Comment: @Arewegood: yes you can; you have a result list, containing BeautifulSoup elements. `for x in myAdds: print x.img.next_sibling`.

Comment: Please, See the edited html. I have `<img>&nbsp; SOME_TEXT</img>` this, and I want to extract "SOME_TEXT". And by using x.img.next_sibling I am getting "None" for each x.

Comment: @Arewegood: that is broken HTML; different parsers will handle it differently. `lxml` will still render it with the text put *after* the `<img>` tag, for example. But the `.get_text()` option works for either.

Comment: Oh, I tried x.get_text(), it gives this error: 
`<type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128) `

Comment: @Arewegood: That is your console; it fails to print the contained unicode text. It'll work if you use `print repr(...)`. BeautifulSoup is working fine.

Comment: I have no problem with beautifulsoup. But is there a way, I can remove the unicode characters too. I am getting result u'\xa0 SOME_TEXT', and I want SOME_TEXT.

Comment: @Arewegood: You have a non-breaking space; use `.strip()` to remove all whitespace from start and end.

Answer (score 0):

```
abc="""
<div class="data">
  <img src="/page1/page2/Images/pic.png" height="13" width="13">
  &nbsp; SOME_TEXT
 </div> """


from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS
s=BS(abc,convertEntities=BS.HTML_ENTITIES)
s.text

u'SOME_TEXT'
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup 3 has been discontinued years ago; you'll have to assume that users use BeautifulSoup 4 these days.

Comment: Also, don't just dump code without an explanation on a user. Do include some exposition as to why the code is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

VAR ="""
<div class="data">
  <img src="/page1/page2/Images/pic.png" height="13" width="13">
  &nbsp; SOME_TEXT
</div>
"""
myAdds = BeautifulSoup(VAR,convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
print myAdds.text
```

Comment: I am getting this error: 
<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: type object 'BeautifulSoup' has no attribute 'HTML_ENTITIES'

Comment: Again, BeautifulSoup 3 has been discontinued *for years* now. The OP is using BeautifulSoup 4; there is little point in repeating snippets of code from BeautifulSoup 3 found on the web, without testing or showing how they work. Don't just dump only code in an answer, and don't use code that is far outdated.